# Is there a website that states which authors have written in Larry Nivens "playground"?

Tags: larry-niven

Is there a website that states which authors have taken the literary ball and run with it in Larry Nivens playground?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.larryniven.net/kzin/authors.shtml

- Poul Anderson
- Dean Ing
- Jerry Pournelle
- SM Stirling
- Greg Bear
- Donald Kingsbury
- Thomas T. Thomas
- Gregory Benford
- Mark O. Martin
- Hal Colebatch
- Paul Chafe
- Jean Lamb
- Warren T. James
- Matthew Joseph Harrington

In addition, Larry Niven co-authored several Known Worlds novels with Edward M. Lerner (... Worlds series)

**Lists of books and stories are available at:**

- http://www.larryniven.net/kzin/reviews.shtml
- http://knownspacetimeline.webs.com/sources.htm

Comment: Nice. Now how about a little help with my bounty question?

Comment: @Major - which one? You can make links in comments by using \[text](URL) syntax